# Object algebras without anonymous inner classes

Tags: object-oriented

In de Oliveira and Cook's [Extensibility for the Masses](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ewcook/Drafts/2012/ecoop2012.pdf) uses Java for its code (it's not about stuff specific to that language though) and the ability to create anonymous inner classes is used extensively, starting from the code in Figure 4. Yet the authors claim that they rely only on a modest set of features and the same could be done e.g. in C# (as of 2012). Would the equivalents in C#, C++, Visual Basic and other languages without anonymous inner classes involve creating ordinary classes implementing the right interface, taking the arguments and storing them in the constructor and using in a single method, and those classes would be instantiated with `new` instead of the interfaces?

Comment: Hello, welcome. Your question seems a bit language-specific to be on-topic here. Maybe you could reword it to be language-independent and just give the languages as examples? I think this invalidates questions 2 and 3, but question 1 could still be answered. This site is about conceptual computer science questions (in your case, object oriented language design).

Comment: Everything you can do in Java with anonymous inner classes you can also do without anonymous inner classes. They are "syntactic sugar"

Comment: @6005, OK, I've edited accordingly.